# Does tensorflow-federated support dynamic batch size?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

Does tensorflow-federated support assigning different batch-size for different simulated devices, and changing batch-size for different epoch?

Answer (score 2):

TFF does support dynamic batch size--this is encoded at the type signature level, in the shape attribute of  `tff.TensorType`. Any dimension with associated shape of `None` will be dynamic. If you have a [`tff.learning.Model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/Model), the `input_spec` attribute should have `None`-size dimension for any dimension you wish to be dynamic.

The exact correct specification type signature is dependent on exactly what you are looking to do with these dynamic shapes. Here is a quick example that might illustrate a little more:

Suppose you have a Keras model `model` and a `tff.simulation.ClientData` object `client_data`. The `input_spec` argument to [`tff.learning.from_keras_model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/from_keras_model) will populate the `tff.learning.Model` `input_spec` directly, so it is here you wish to specify that your batch dimension can vary:

```
input_spec = collections.OrderedDict(
    x=tf.TensorSpec(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 784]),
    y=tf.TensorSpec(dtype=tf.int64, shape=[None]),
)

def model_fn():
  tff_model = tff.learning.from_keras_model(
      keras_model=model,
      input_spec=input_spec,
      # other args,...
  )
```

Then, inside your Python-driving training loop, you can use different batch sizes across different rounds of training (or even within the same round I suppose), like so (assuming we wrote a function called `_whatever_batch_size_I_want` which takes the round number as an argument and returns whatever batch size is appropriate for that round):

```
fedavg_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
    model_fn=model_fn, # other args, ...)

state = fedavg_process.initialize()

for k in range(NUM_ROUNDS):
  batch_size = _whatever_batch_size_you_want(k)
  sampled_client_ids = random.choices(
      client_data.client_ids, k=NUM_CLIENTS_PER_ROUND)
  client_datasets = [
      client_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(x) for x in sampled_client_ids]
  batched_client_datasets = [ds.batch(batch_size) for ds in client_datasets]
  state = fedavg_process.next(state, batched_client_datasets)
```

You can do even fancier things with dynamic shapes and input spec arguments if desired; for example, you can train a sequence-processing model which takes variable-length sequences by specifying the sequence dimension to have size `None` as well.